# Objecto javascript sempre sendo criado em ordem cresente

Tags: javascript

Estou lidando com um código similar em um projeto:

```
var groupedObject = {};
groupedObject['2016'] = {};
groupedObject['2022'] = {};
groupedObject['2014'] = {};
groupedObject['2021'] = {};
console.log(groupedObject);
```

Nao importa a ordem em que os valores do objeto são criados, o log SEMPRE retorna o objeto em ascending order

Output:

```
2014:{}
2016:{}
2021:{}
2022:{}
```

Eu não quero esse comportamento. Alguém saberia explicar porquê? Como retornar o objeto na ordem em que ele está sendo criado?

Comment: tem que usar um array

Comment: @TomásAntunes, Infelizmente na minha situação preciso que seja um objeto. E preciso que respeite a ordem em que está sendo criado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando os nomes das *keys* forem puramente numéricos, eles são automaticamente organizados em ordem crescente, não importa em que ordem você os inseriu. Se não forem numéricos, a ordem será mantida de acordo com a ordem inserida.

> Não consegui perceber a importância dessa ordem, já que, não importa
>   de "2016" esteja antes de "2014" se quando você quiser acessar uma
>   chave pelo nome, ela vai estar lá (?).

Mas se quer mesmo ordenar pela ordem de inserção, sugiro adicionar pelo menos 1 letra aos nomes das *keys*. Creio que isso não prejudicaria em nada a sua aplicação.

Seria algo do tipo:

```js
var groupedObject = {};
groupedObject['n2016'] = {};
groupedObject['n2022'] = {};
groupedObject['n2014'] = {};
groupedObject['n2021'] = {};
console.log(groupedObject);
```

Ou poderia usar um *underscore*:

```js
var groupedObject = {};
groupedObject['2016_'] = {};
groupedObject['2022_'] = {};
groupedObject['2014_'] = {};
groupedObject['2021_'] = {};
console.log(groupedObject);
```

Comment: Todas as respostas me ajudaram a chegar numa solução, mas acredito que esta é a que melhor atende minha situação. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

A ordem de inserção no objeto não é garantida pela especificação.

No entanto se utilizar um [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) isso já é verdade. Este fornece-lhe a mesma funcionalidade garantindo a ordem de inserção, mas a sintaxe já será diferente.

A criação passa a ser:

```
var groupedObject = new Map();
```

Para atribuir um valor a uma chave tem de utilizar o método `set` passando a chave e o valor:

```
groupedObject.set('2016', {});
```

Para obter o valor de uma chave tem de utilizar o `get` indicando o nome da chave:

```
let valor = groupedObject.get('2016')
```

Percorrer todos os elementos é feito com [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (let obj of groupedObject){
    //fazer algo com obj
}
```

Veja o seu exemplo em `Map`:

```js
var groupedObject = new Map();
groupedObject.set('2016', {});
groupedObject.set('2022', {});
groupedObject.set('2014', {});
groupedObject.set('2021', {});

for (let obj of groupedObject){
  console.log(obj);
}

console.log(groupedObject.get('2016'));
```

Comment: Pensei na mesma solução. Vale o aviso de que o Map não é suportado em browsers antigos (IE < 11), e parcialmente suportado no IE 11.

Comment: @bfavaretto Agradeço o comentário, e sim é de facto uma ressalva importante.

Answer (score 1):

O problema não está no `console.log` e sim no objeto JS que por definição não mantem a ordem, encontrei uma alternativa no SOen que pode ajudar a chegar no resultado que você deseja.

```js
var groupedObject = {};
groupedObject[' ' +2016] = {};
groupedObject[' ' +2022] = {};
groupedObject[' ' +2014] = {};
groupedObject[' ' +2021] = {};
console.log(groupedObject);
```

ref: [How to prevent automatic sort of Object numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351816/how-to-prevent-automatic-sort-of-object-numeric-property)